# "I bicycle" - "I ride bikes" - "I bike"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-order

What's the best way to say it?

"I like to ride bicycles" is correct but pretty lame sounding...

Is "I bicycle" correct? Or is it too obscure to be good usage?

Comment: Generally, since one can only ride one bike at a time, the usual generic is _I ride a bike_. That indicates that bicycling is your normal mode of transport, in the context of the conversation.

Comment: @JohnLawler: An enthusiast might own more than one bicycle – a trail bike, a racing bike, a city bike, etc. In that case, there would be nothing wrong with "I like to ride bicycles."

Comment: Of course. But it doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Sure - I guess it depends on what the O.P. is trying to say (which wasn't really well-specified...)

Comment: @Wes Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/115980/edit) your question to provide context for the situation where you want to talk about riding bicycles.

Answer (score 7):

What *I* would say is *I like cycling*, or *I like riding bikes*. (I could say *I like bicycling*, but I probably wouldn't, unless I'd just been talking to somebody who only rides tricycles).

Or, if you didn't really want the *like* in there: *I cycle*. In context (if it is already established that we're talking about bikes) I'd say *I ride*.

I wouldn't usually say *I bike* (though others would). But I'll use that in specific contexts: *I used to bike to work*.

Answer (score 2):

"I bike" is acceptable, as well.

You could probably get away with "I have a bike", too, honestly.